# Use sql in python or c ++ to output output samples based on input data

Tags: python, c++, mysql, sql

The problem is as follows, I need to input (can be saved to the database, or csv file, excel file, etc.) I try to solve the problem with MySQL because the same order may have multiple products, they will branch. And the situation of the same product in different orders is not the same, which brings me a great challenge. If a great god can help me, thank you very much.

```
input:

Orderid   Itemid    Quantity
001         a1       1
001         a2       1 
002         a1       1
003         a1       1
003         a2       1 
004         a1       1
005         a1       3 
006         a2       1    
007         a1       1 
008         a1       1 

output：

ordersum  percent   Cumulative   itemdetail
4        50.00%    50.00%      a1[1]
2        25.00%    75.00%      a1[1]a2[1]   
1        12.50%    87.50%      a1[3]
1        12.50%    100.00%     a2[1]
```

I have been writing for an afternoon. The statistical results are not very satisfactory. Note that the problem fields I described are different from my original table fields. My thinking is as follows:

```
SET @csum: = 0;
select order volume, shop proportion, concat (round ((@ csum: = @csum + shop proportion), 2), '', '%') cumulative proportion, shop name
from
(select t1.store name, t1.order quantity, concat (round (t1.order quantity / t2.ordersum * 100,2), '', '%')
from
(select shop shop name, count (distinct (order number)) order quantity
from order20190801
group by shop
order by count (distinct (order number)) desc) t1,
(select count (distinct (order number)) ordersum
from order20190801) t2) t3
```

## 5.8 seconds or so A bit long! !!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I have been writing for an afternoon. The statistical results are not very satisfactory. Note that the problem fields I described are different from my original table fields. My thinking is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

```html
SET @csum := 0;
select 订单量,
concat(round(订单量 / 订单总量* 100 ,5),'','%') 订单占比, 
concat(round(@csum := @csum + concat(round(订单量 / 订单总量* 100 ,5),'','%'),5),'','%') AS 累计占比 ,
订单明细
from(
  select count(订单明细) 订单量,订单明细
  from (
    select 订单编号,GROUP_CONCAT(商家编码,'|',货品数量) 订单明细
    from order20190801
    group by 订单编号
    )t1
  group by 订单明细
  order by  count(订单明细) desc 
  )t2,(select count(distinct(订单编号)) 订单总量 from order20190801
  )t3

#10.437秒！！！
```

Solve my own problem, but the execution time is relatively long, if there are optimization suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it